# Code involving mdframed and scrlttr2 that compiled with TL 2014 but does not compile with 2015

Tags: koma-script, mdframed, scrlttr2

The following code used to compile with TeX Live 2014, but does not compile with TeX Live 2015. I now get the error:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
                \endgroup
l.158   \closing{Yours Sincerely}
```

This may be related to changes in KOMA. None of the other relevant package appear to have changed recently. I'd be interested in an explanation of why this no longer works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\surroundwithmdframed[linewidth=2pt]{tabular}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}

\def\today{6th April, 2015}
\begin{letter}{Addressee}

  \opening{Dear,}

  \closing{Yours Sincerely}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\closing ` uses a tabular internally while measuring the width of itself. Surrounding that with a frame leads to the error message you encounter as shown in chat already.

Comment: @Johannes_B And why on earth don't you give an answer instead of a comment? You waste my time with this behaviour!

Comment: @KeksDose Sorry for wasting your time. Please post an answer.

Comment: From looking at my history, it looks lke my "solution" was simply to remove the line `\surroundwithmdframed[linewidth=2pt]{tabular}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\closing` is a very special tabular environment.

Boiling down to the absolute minimum, the following MWE comes up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
%\surroundwithmdframed[linewidth=2pt]{tabular}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\faheem}
\settowidth{\faheem}{%
    \begin{mdframed}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        lala
    \end{tabular}
\end{mdframed}
}
\end{document}
```

You cannot use frames inside a `\settowidth` command.
You cannot have a frame inside

Comment: I'm not following exactly what goes wrong here. Can you elaborate? Specifically, what does the `settowidth` command correspond to in my original code?

Comment: @FaheemMitha We talked about this in december, i just looked at the chat transscript and copied the example over here since an answer was requested. Can you check the transscript if you see anything helpful for you? If so, you can add it to the answer. If not, ping me and i will add something  later.

Comment: Could you add a url for the relevant portion of the chat transcript? Thanks.

Comment: @FaheemMitha http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=26153761#26153761