# How to produce a partial double frame using tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, border

[`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) seems a pretty powerful package, so I'm pretty sure it can do what I want, but I can't find it.

This is what I'd like to produce:

[image]

And this is what I'm able to get:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\one}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  after skip=10pt,
  sharp corners,
  borderline={1pt}{-3pt}{black},
  toprule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=.5pt,
  leftrule=.5pt,
  colback=white,
  #1
}
\newtcbox{\two}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  after skip=10pt,
  sharp corners,
  borderline west={1pt}{3pt}{black},
  borderline south={1pt}{3pt}{black},
  toprule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=.5pt,
  leftrule=.5pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=black,
  #1}
\newtcbox{\three}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  after skip=10pt,
  sharp corners,
  borderline west={1pt}{-3pt}{black},
  borderline south={1pt}{-3pt}{black},
  toprule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=.5pt,
  leftrule=.5pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=black,
  #1}

\begin{document}
\one{I don't what the top and right frame border.}

\two{I don't what the lines to cross at the bottom left corner.}

\three{I'd like to join the lines at the bottom left corner.}
\end{document}
```

I have a working frame using [`mdframed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed), but I can't use that as I need it to work within `\settowidth`, and [that one doesn't](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314106/4888).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366790/31729

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I hadn't noticed that one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use, for example,

```
\newtcbox{\three}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,colback=white,enhanced,overlay unbroken={%
            \draw[thick,red,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west)--(interior.south east);
        },
    #1}
```

Here is the output

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\three}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,colback=white,enhanced,overlay unbroken={%
            \draw[thick,red,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west)--(interior.south east);
        },
    #1}

\begin{document}

\three{here is some text}

\end{document}
```

If you'd like it to be able to break across pages, then you could define, for example:

```
\newtcolorbox{four}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    frame hidden,
    colback=white,
    overlay unbroken={%
            \draw[thick,red,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west)--(interior.south east);
        },
    overlay first={
            \draw[thick,red,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west);
        },
    overlay middle={
            \draw[thick,red,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west);
        },
    overlay last={
            \draw[thick,red,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west)--(interior.south east);
        },
    #1,
}
```

and then use:

```
\begin{four}
    \lipsum
\end{four}
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer. At the moment, I don't think I need page breaks, but then again, a few days ago I didn't even need the frame ;-)