# tcolorbox causes horizontal offset for marginnote

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, marginnote

I'm using the [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to get some frames into my document output (the how-to about the partial frame was [kindly provided by cmhuges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391788/4888)). I'm also using [`marginnote`](https://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) to output margin notes, both from the framed text and from the running text.

I noticed that if I specify a `left` offset, the margin note gets displaced horizontally by that offset (it also gets displaced by specifying a nonzero leftrule thickness, and probably by other measures as well, but I didn't experiment much more than that).

I haven't found a way to prevent this, other than saying `\hskip-10pt` in the margin note. Obviously this is not ideal, as the frame parameters may change over time.

I have tried fiddling with `\marginnoteleftadjust` and `\marginnoterightadjust`, but as the marginnote docs suggested this had no effect, as I'm using a current pdfLaTeX version.

I'd appreciate any ideas how to get the notes from within the tcolorbox at the correct horizontal position, probably it's (again) something I don't see ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newtcbox{\one}[1][]{%
    enhanced,%
    frame hidden,%
    colback=white,%
    boxsep=0pt,%
    left=10pt,% <---marginnote displacement!
    top=0pt,%
    bottom=0pt,%
    right=0pt,%
    leftrule=0pt,%
    rightrule=0pt,%
    left skip=20pt,%
    after skip=\baselineskip,%
    overlay unbroken={%
        \draw[thin,black,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west)--(interior.south east);
        },#1}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
regular text\marginnote{correct}.

\one{tcolorbox text\marginnote{wrong}}

\one{tcolorbox text\marginnote{\hskip-10pt manual}}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269426/wrong-marginnote-positions-inside-a-tikzpicture-with-xelatex for the same problem. The answer given there should also solve this question.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thanks a lot! I tried that and it works. Great stuff. Would you like to post that as an answer? The other two questions don't come up when searching for this in relation to `tcolorbox`.

Comment: This question is already marked as duplicate with a link to the other question. Therefore, I think that a reader will find it now following the link.